# Why does R introduce NA's? No commas, just plain numbers like 4438

Tags: r

I don't think this has been answered (before). Why do I get "NAs introduced by coercion", when the values are indeed plain numbers? As far as I can tell there is no commas involved (which seems like a common source for this problem).

This is my script:

```
# load packages

library(tidyverse)


# Get data

UI_url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OpportunityInsights/EconomicTracker/main/data/UI%20Claims%20-%20State%20-%20Weekly.csv"

ui_state_weekly <- read.csv(url(UI_url))

# convert chr to numeric
test <- ui_state_weekly %>% mutate(test = as.numeric(contclaims_rate_combined))
summary(test) # 102 NA's

# Find the values that cause the problem with:

which(is.na(as.numeric(ui_state_weekly$contclaims_rate_combined)) != is.na(ui_state_weekly$contclaims_rate_combined))
```

As you can tell, r reports numbers like:

```
[1] 4438 4439 4440 4441 4442 4443 4444 4445 4446 4447 4448 4449 4450 4451 4452 4453 4454 4455 4456 4457 4458
[22] 4459 4460 4461 4462 4463 4464 4465 4466 4467 4468 4469 4470 4471 4472 4473 4474 4475 4476 4477 4478 4479
```

They should work with as.numeric(). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 612 cells contain just a single period `.`

Comment: The column `contclaims_rate_combined` is of type `character` (see `str(ui_state_weekly)`)

Comment: @dario this is not really relevant to the question, as it does not explain why NAs are introduced when converting this column to type `numeric`

Comment: @denisafonin Sorry but I disagree, It does answer the reason for the NAs, because generally, you can't convert character to numbers (It works only in some special cases)

Comment: This question is really about how to read in data with an alternate specification for NA.

Comment: @Adam That would require knowing there are `.` chars in the first place, which OP didn't know. That's more like a follow-up question _after_ realizing there are `.` chars.

Comment: @tdy fair point. But once I found it I would not go and apply the solutions to coerce it. Once I found it I would go and update my read line. That is more of my point. Still need the same diagnostic steps (or a data dictionary).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other solutions fix the problem after the fact. The issue isn't really an issue, more like a data definition problem. In this data set, it seems that "." is being used for "NA". So set that when reading in the file rather than trying to fix it after the fact.

Use `read.table` in base and set the `na.strings`.

```r
ui_state_weekly <- read.table(url(UI_url), header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote = "\"",
                              na.strings = ".")
```

Or this may be easier since you have to worry about fewer settings.

```r
library(readr)

ui_state_weekly <- read_csv(url(UI_url), na = c("", "NA", "."))
```

When you do this, you can see that the column of interest now reads in as double and does not require coercion.

Comment: I change this to the answer as I feel that this solution is probably more helpful overall. As Adam correctly pointed out, it is just a matter of fixing the code for reading in the file and then there is no problem. I should say that I tried @denisafonin solution first, and it also worked -- some people might find that useful as well.

Answer (score 3):

You have some single dot values (`"."`) which cannot be changed to numeric.

```
ui_state_weekly$contclaims_rate_combined[c(4438, 4439, 4440)]
#[1] "." "." "."
```

You can turn them to empty value and then change to numeric.

```
library(dplyr)

test <- ui_state_weekly %>% 
          mutate(test = as.numeric(sub('.', '', contclaims_rate_combined, 
                          fixed = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 2):

In regards to this part of your code:

```
# Find the values that cause the problem with:

which(is.na(as.numeric(ui_state_weekly$contclaims_rate_combined)) != is.na(ui_state_weekly$contclaims_rate_combined))

[1] 4438 4439 4440 4441 4442 4443 4444 4445 4446 4447 4448 4449 4450 4451 4452 4453 4454 4455 4456 4457 4458
[22] 4459 4460 4461 4462 4463 4464 4465 4466 4467 4468 4469 4470 4471 4472 4473 4474 4475 4476 4477 4478 4479
```

What you are getting is not the list of values, but indexes of values that result in NA when converted to numerical. Try this:

```
index = which(is.na(as.numeric(ui_state_weekly$contclaims_rate_combined)) != is.na(ui_state_weekly$contclaims_rate_combined))

ui_state_weekly$contclaims_rate_combined[index]
```

And you will see that rows with these indexes contain dots in column `contclaims_rate_combined`:

```
[1] "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "."
 [38] "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "."
 [75] "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "." "."
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a zero where needed with a fixer function `fix_num`. Single `.` with no numbers are turned to `NA`.

```
fix_num <- function(x) {
  rpl <- grep('^\\.\\d+', x)
  x[rpl] <- gsub('\\.', '0\\.', x[rpl])
  x[grep('^.$', x)] <- NA
  return(as.numeric(x))
}

library(dplyr)
test <- ui_state_weekly %>% 
  mutate(contclaims_rate_combined_fix=fix_num(contclaims_rate_combined)) 
summary(test[18:19])
# contclaims_rate_combined contclaims_rate_combined_fix
# Length:4539              Min.   : 0.307              
# Class :character         1st Qu.: 2.980              
# Mode  :character         Median : 7.130              
#                          Mean   : 8.890              
#                          3rd Qu.:12.600              
#                          Max.   :71.500              
#                          NA's   :126
```